# Where did the chat room shortcuts go?

Tags: discussion, chat

Can't find the links to chat anymore. Where did they go? Used to have it on the side bar but now it's gone and I have no idea where to go to find it. This site seems to have a lot of problems!

Comment: I don't know what all the other problems are, but feel free to post more bugs or feature requests on meta.

Comment: What chat link are you talking about? Can you show an example on another site if you can't find it here?

Answer (score 4):

The chat link in the sidebar isn't always present on main. I think it's always there on meta, though.

But in any case, there is always a link to chat in the top left menu:

[image]